# Error in arara: unresolvable property or identifier: file

Tags: arara

<sup>**Disclaimer:** Since arara 5.1 is now live on TeX Live and we have some significant changes in the rule format, I am antecipating the inevitable and asking the question myself. Hope it helps! `:)`</sup>

So I recently updated my TeX distro and noticed `arara` has been updated from version 4 to 5. At the time of my writing, the aforementioned software is in version `5.1` in CTAN.

I have a custom rule named `foo` with the following content:

```
!config
identifier: foo
name: Foo
commands:
- name: The Foo program
  command: >
    @{
        return getCommand('foo', file);
    }
arguments: []
```

Pretty straightforward, it simply runs `foo` on my current file. This rule was working in `arara` 4.0, but now the new version raises the following error:

```
DETAILS ---------------------------------------------------------
[Error: unresolvable property or identifier: file]
[Near : {...
return getCommand('foo', file); ....}]

           ^
[Line: 2, Column: 30]
```

It was working before, I know it! What happened? Can you help me?

Answer (score 8):

This behaviour is now expected, as described in the project [CHANGELOG](https://gitlab.com/islandoftex/arara/-/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) and the current user manual (try `texdoc arara` in your terminal to open the corresponding PDF file). According to the latter:

> `arara` previously had the file name string as the `file` variable in the rule context. As of version 5.0, support for this variable has been dropped. Users should favour the `reference` variable instead, since it holds the absolute, canonical representation of the file name as a proper `File` object.

So, `file` is no more. Simply replace the `file` occurrences in your rule by `reference` and you should be good to go:

```
!config
identifier: foo
name: Foo
commands:
- name: The Foo program
  command: >
    @{
        return getCommand('foo', reference);
    }
arguments: []
```

A simple test:

```
Processing 'mydoc.tex' (size: 23 B, last modified: 04/11/2020
12:44:24), please wait.

[DR] (Foo) The Foo program
-----------------------------------------------------------------
Authors: No authors provided
About to run: [ foo, /home/paulo/mydoc.tex ] @ 

Total: 0.25 seconds
```

That's it! Hope it helps! `:)`