# Automatically Typeset two Versions of a Document - Update needed for Arara 5.0

Tags: arara

With version 4 of arara, I was able to typeset two versions of a document nicely by inputting different files with different definitions according to arara rules.

Unfortunately, this has stopped working with arara 5.0. I know that in the yaml rule, I need to replace `file` with `reference`. I also experimented with using `getCommand` and `return getCommand`, however to no success (not that I'm experienced in programming).

In the following, I tried to give a MWE of both my .tex file as well as of the yaml rule.
Any help is appreciated!

**Latex Document:**

```
% arara: pdfversions: {rules: _lv}
% arara: pdfversions: {rules: _sv}
\ifdefined\Version
\else
    \def\Version{_lv}
\fi
%
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage[english, ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\input{\Version} %calls file _lv oder _ls, depending on arara rule
%file _lv contains (among others): \newenvironment*{LV}{\LARGE\color{red}}{\hspace{0.25cm}\normalsize}
%file _sv contains (among others): \newenvironment*{LV}{\LARGE\color{white}}{\hspace{0.25cm}\normalsize}
%
\begin{document}
\begin{LV}
test
\end{LV}
\end{document}
```

The idea of the arara rule is that that it defines either _lv or _sv in the beginning, thus loads the file _ls or _sv, then typesets the file according to the definitions on the corresponding file, creates a PDF with the ending _LV or _SV and finally opens the PDF.

**YAML file with rules:**

```
!config
# PDFLaTeX rule for arara to return 2 PDF Files, a teacher and a student version
# author: based on code from Chris Hughes
# requires arara 4.0+
# % arara: pdfversions
# % arara: pdfversions: {rules: _lv}
# % arara: pdfversions: {rules: _sv}
identifier: pdfversions
name: PDFVersions
commands:
- command: <arara> pdflatex "\def\Version{@{rules}}\input{@{file}}"
- command: <arara> @{ isWindows( "cmd /c move", "mv" ) } @{getBasename(file)}.pdf @{getBasename(file)}@{rules.toUpperCase()}.pdf
- command: <arara> open @{getBasename(file)}@{rules.toUpperCase()}.pdf
arguments:
- identifier: rules
  flag: <arara> @{parameters.rules}
  default: _lv
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned: from arara v5 on, you cannot access `file` anymore. `reference` is there to help because it is a properly typed file object. There has been [a question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/538046/124577) about this major change in arara v5.

Please note, that the `<arara>` shorthand syntax is deprecated (will be removed in v6). Support for returning string commands has been removed in favor of the much cleaner `getCommand` approach.

All of the above changes are also detailed in the [changelog](https://gitlab.com/islandoftex/arara/-/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md).

The following is untested:

```
!config
# PDFLaTeX rule for arara to return 2 PDF Files,
# a teacher and a student version
# author: based on code from Chris Hughes
# requires arara 4.0+
# % arara: pdfversions
# % arara: pdfversions: {rules: _lv}
# % arara: pdfversions: {rules: _sv}
identifier: pdfversions
name: PDFVersions
commands:
- command: >
    @{
      return getCommand('pdflatex', '\\def\\Version{' + rules + '}\\input{'
                        + reference.getName() + '}');
    }
- command: >
    @{
      output = getBasename(reference.getName()) + rules.toUpperCase() + '.pdf';
      return getCommand(isWindows([ 'cmd', '/c', 'move' ], 'mv'),
             reference.getName(), output);
    }
- command: >
    @{
      return getCommand('open', getBasename(reference.getName()) +
                        rules.toUpperCase() + '.pdf');
    }
arguments:
- identifier: rules
  flag: >
    @{
      return parameters.rules;
    }
  default: _lv
```

Comment: Wow, thanks very much! In the second command, I had to change the `reference.getName()`, since like this, the .tex file was moved / deleted. I changed it to `- command: >
    @{
      output = getBasename(reference.getName()) + rules.toUpperCase() + '.pdf';
      input = getBasename(reference.getName()) + '.pdf';
      return getCommand('cp', input, output);
    }
`
which works like a charm. Thanks again!